# Best practices for setting up Routes in AngularJS the RESTful way

Tags: angularjs, rest, crud

I'm building a UI using AngularJS that consumes a REST service:

Here is the Server API

```
/items/ GET
/items/:id GET
/items/ POST (to create new item)
/items/:id PUT (to edit item)
/items/:id DELETE
```

What are the best practices when setting up the routes in Angular? These routes would map to the server REST API, but obviously there is a problem. I'm guessing I would need the action as part of the URL, right? Something like this:

Angular Routes:

```
/items/
/items/:id
/items/new 
/items/:id/edit
/items/:id/delete
```

However the above pattern also has a problem. /items/new will match both /items/:id and /items/new so what is the best practice when setting up a route for create?

Comment: Are you using UI-router? In UI-router `items/new` and `items/:id` are two different routes

Comment: Yes I'm using UI-router. So if the user types in /items/new in the URL, what if there is actually an id that is equal to "new"?

Comment: Why do you want to use "new" as id? Why not `Integers` or `UUID` for id's? How about `'/add'` for adding new item

Comment: the route can be the same for all the REST calls,depending upon user actions you can have multiple factory calls each for post,get, get all, put, delete

Comment: @VamsiV sure, I would use only integers for ids. But does Angular assume that? If I have two routes (items/new and items/:id), then Angular expects that my id should be an integer?

Comment: @V31 so if the user types in /items in the URL bar, which template do I display to the user: the list of items (/items GET), or the create new (/items POST)?

Comment: If you are inserting a new record then their wont be any REST API and it will be blank form then you can use /newItem and to fetch all the items /items. yes the you need to routers to make it simple

Comment: @V31 If the user is inserting a new record then I need to display a form to the user so the user can enter the details of the record that needs to be inserted. So the view/template is different for /items/ GET and /items/ POST

Comment: You can use regex for params `'/items/{id:[0-9]{1,4}}'` this means allow only numbers `0 to 9` and `1 to 4` characters long

Comment: @VamsiV Is that the recommended approach?  Going back to my original question, are my Angular routes OK?

Comment: I think it is the only way, cant say it is recommended by anyone. I use this approach, working fine for me. It `will not allow empty id ` so this route will not match `/items/` so it will be unique

Answer (score 6):

Also keep in mind that the client side, Angular, routes you're defining could be dependent on your UI. The routes you've defined are more like a traditional web application where you click an "Add New" button that takes you to a new page that has a form that you fill out.  However, this may not be the pattern you use for a Single Page App (SPA) as is often created with Angular.

By this I mean that most of the SPA apps I've done don't actually have a standalone "/items/new" route on the client side. Instead, the "/items/new" functionality is handled on the "/items/" route/partial ("page" in traditional web app terms). This page lists the existing items, and there is a form on this page that you can fill out to create a new item. Or, there is an "Add New" button on this page (just like a traditional web app); but, clicking it either slides in a modal form or ng-shows a form that is already defined (but initially hidden) on the /items/ partial template.

Upon submission, the controller hits against "POST /items/" on the server to create the new item, updates scope with the return value from the POST (assuming success, this would be the new item info), and clears/re-hides the "new" form.

Bottom line -- keep in mind that in a SPA you may not actually need a "/items/new" if the UI is such that the new is handled as a capability of the item list page. Of course, if you're needing it to be a standalone page as an addressable endpoint (i.e. you're planning to link to this from multiple places, not just from within the app), then you'll obviously need a direct route.

In our case, we typically don't need a named route for it in our apps and we just have it serviced as a capability of the "/items/" route.

Comment: Got it thanks. But, if in my case I decide that I need a new view (and not just a popup from the existing page), then the naming the route /items/new would not be breaking REST conventions right?

Comment: to be clear, REST conventions are generally applied to API routes and by definition need the METHOD to fully specify. In the case of your Angular routes, you're choosing to make the REST like, but obviously you don't have the METHOD, so it's not going to be REST.

Comment: Having said that, yes, using something like "/items/new" is certainly common. You just have to disambiguate between the "command" (i.e. what the METHOD does in an actual REST scenario) vs. a valid ID. This is what Vamsi explained well in the other answer. If your IDs can be alpha, then you'll need to explicitly exclude your command(s) from the ID namespace in another fashion (e.g. /items/-new if dash is disallowed in the id).

Answer (score 2):

Using UI-Router we can setup client side routing.

Make sure you disable html5 routes, because some browsers still doesn't support html5 and they hit the server api instead of hitting the client route

You can do this by setting `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);` in `app.config` method while defining angular `app`

```
/items/                     - this is for listing items
/items/{id:[0-9]{1,4}}      - this is for displaying one item in detail
/items/add                  - for displaying new item form
/items/:id/edit             - for displaying existing item in Form for editing
/items/:id/delete           - **This is not required, I mean you just hit the API when
                                use clicks delete, we cant show any deletion form**
```

You can use regex for params `'/items/{id:[0-9]{1,4}}'` this means `allow only numbers 0 to 9` and `1 to 4 characters long`

Comment: Thanks. Any particular reason you changed "new" to "add"?

Comment: `For Readability`,  `items/add` can be easily read as adding item, than `items/new`

Comment: Words like `add` and `create` are often used interchangeably, while in fact they are quite different: _creating_ refers to instantiating a completely new instance and persisting it for the first time (like registering a new user) and _adding_ means taking something (potentially existing) and placing them into some sort of collection (like adding user to project collaborators). Readability isn't really a strong argument here.